# Change the default error message in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Currently I am using this to deal with users inputting any wrong data into my app:

```
options(shiny.sanitize.errors = TRUE)
```

It returns this error message:

```
Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

Is there a way to change the content of this message to something else like, say "Invalid username. Please try again", i don't want to use try-catch and want to just change this default error message.

Comment: What about using `tryCatch()`?

Comment: There's no way to change it. I would just handle the error where it happens. A specific global error message like that may also confuse users when other unexpected errors occur.

Comment: would you run a tryCatch across the entire code? I want just 1 generic error message basically.

Comment: It's not possible to run a tryCatch across the entire app.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default text with css:

```
tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-output-error{visibility: hidden}")),

tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-output-error:after{content: 'Invalid username. Please try again';
visibility: visible}")),
```

But as greg L said, this message will appear for any error - so you should choose a text that holds globally.

Comment: Should this have a  "  after `visible}` ?